# Using a list of column names of a dataframe in order to create a new list of column names where a condition applies on the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following list containing the column names to be used to apply my condition on:

```
    text_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=obj_types).columns.values.tolist()
```

I then use the following list (text_cols) in order to make a new list where the condition applies:

```
    if(df[df[text_cols] > 10]):
        cols_to_remove=df.columns.get_values()
```

So, as you can see, I pass my list as a parameter in my if condition and then check if the value of the next column name from the list in my dataframe is superior to 10, if it is the case, I get the value of the current column and add it to my `cols_to_remove` list.

The only issue is, it is not working as intended and I instead get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression `df[df[colname] > 10]` will work in case if `df[colname]` is a `pd.Series`. That case this expression returns a bollean index:

```
df[colname] > 10
Out:
0  True
1  False
2  False
3  True
```

You can use this series as an index for the `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df[df[column] > 10]
```

But if you hav a df, for example,

```
In[8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0,12,2], 'col2': [13, 11, 5]})
Out[8]: 
   col1  col2
0     0    13
1    12    11
2     2     5
```

if you do

```
In [9]: df > 10                                                                 
Out[9]: 
    col1   col2
0  False   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
```

you'l get a pd.DataFrame, which can't be used as an index. So, an error data advices you to use `all()` or `any()` depending on your task, for example,

```
In [11]: (df > 10).all(axis=1)                                                  
Out[11]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

- this is one-dimensional index. So, you can slice dataframe this way:

```
In [12]: df[(df > 10).all(axis=1)]                                              
Out[12]: 
   col1  col2
1    12    11

In [13]: df[(df > 10).any(axis=1)]                                              
Out[13]: 
   col1  col2
0     0    13
1    12    11
```

I guess, it will resolve the error in your case. Just use correct function - `all`, `any` or just choose one column.

**Edit**
`all` is a logical `and` for *all* elements (all set to the `True`), and `any` is logical `or` for *all* elements (at least, one is `True`).